# algorithm with struct and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i made a simple friend- list using struct and pointers but i have some problem in the code' its not printing the right thing

```
    typedef struct friends {
    int namesize;
    char* myfriends;
}friends;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numfriends = 0;
    int*p_friends = &numfriends;
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    printf("Welcome , here is a list of your friends \n");
    printf("plesase enter the number of your friends \n");
    scanf("%d", &numfriends); //gets the number of the friends
    printf("you have %d friends \n", numfriends);

    friends *f= malloc(sizeof(friends) * numfriends); // malloc
    printf("now please enter thier'S name \n");
    for (i = 0; i < numfriends; i++)
    {
        count++; // for looking at the number of the friend
        (f+i)->myfriends= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * numfriends); // malloc
        printf("enter the name of friend NO.%d ", count);
        fgets((f + i)->myfriends,20,stdin); // entering the names of the friends
        (f +i)-> namesize = strlen((f + i)->myfriends) + 1;
        ((f + i)->myfriends) = (char*)realloc((f + i)->myfriends, sizeof(char) * numfriends * (f + i)->namesize); //realloc

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numfriends; j++)
    {
        printf("The name of friend NO %d is: %s \n", j + 1, ((f + j)->myfriends)); //printing the names
        free((f + j)->myfriends);
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and when im trying to print the friend list :
[image]

how can i solve that?

Comment: To begin with, what does `(f+i)->myfriends= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * numfriends);` followed by `fgets((f + i)->myfriends,20,stdin);` do? Hint: it doesn't do what you think it does because both of them write different information to `(f+i)->myfriends`.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct friends {
    int namesize;
    char* myfriends;
}friends;

#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 20

int main(void){
    int numfriends = 0;
    //int*p_friends = &numfriends;//unused
    int i = 0, count = 0;
    printf("Welcome , here is a list of your friends \n");
    printf("plesase enter the number of your friends \n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &numfriends); //%*c eat newline
    printf("you have %d friends \n", numfriends);

    friends *f= malloc(sizeof(friends) * numfriends);
    printf("now please enter thier'S name \n");
    for (i = 0; i < numfriends; i++){
        count++; // for looking at the number of the friend
        f[i].myfriends = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_NAME_SIZE + 1));//f[i]. short than (f+i)->
        printf("enter the name of friend NO.%d ", count);
        fgets(f[i].myfriends, MAX_NAME_SIZE + 1, stdin); // entering the names of the friends
        f[i].myfriends[strcspn(f[i].myfriends, "\n")] = '\0'; //remove newline
        f[i].namesize = strlen(f[i].myfriends) + 1;
        f[i].myfriends = realloc(f[i].myfriends, f[i].namesize);//Cast is not necessary in C. alos sizeof(char) is always 1 in C.
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numfriends; j++){
        printf("The name of friend NO %d is: %s \n", j + 1, f[j].myfriends); //printing the names
        free(f[j].myfriends);
    }
    free(f);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```